# IReport BigDecimal format "R$ #,##0.00" Monetary Value in Charts

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart, bigdecimal

I have a *JasperReports* chart, In the report, the `field` `$F{soma}` is `BigDecimal`, at the`database` `MySQL` is `Decimal(19,2)`. I'm using this `sql`:  `select SUM(valor) as soma` to get the field  `$F{soma}`. 
Printing just  `$F{soma}` i get labels like : `1.500,20`. Without format expression. What i need is to show labels like : `"R$ 1,520.20"`.

Tried this:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("R$ #,##0.00").format(Double.valueOf($F{soma}))
```

But no success, so if someone can point me a direction, i'll be thankful.

Have not reputation to post images, but links bellow are about the `field` types..

Field in `MySQL`:

[image]

Labels being printed (without  format expression)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with no success?, show the jrxml (field declaration and how you set the value), with complete error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `$F{soma}` is a `BigDecimal` field then just write

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("R$ #,##0.00").format($F{soma});
```

Comment: I've tried and it gives me this:   `Error filling print... java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`

Comment: But the parameter is a `BigDecimal`

Comment: `BigDecimal` in the database and at the `IReport` chart.

Comment: See my `sql`: `select SUM(valor) as soma`...Maybe it help.

Comment: Is it possible to IReport to "retrieve" `soma` as a string, even if it is a `BigDecimal`? I ask because of the error message.

Comment: Not familiar with `NVL`, at the query editor it says: FUNCTION `myDatabase.NVL does not exist`

Comment: It's MySQL database.

Comment: Then try ``IFNULL(SUM(valor),0)``

Comment: I've changed, and get the same `exception` `Error filling print... java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Numbe‌​r`

Comment: Rechecked, `FUNCTION myDatabase.NVL does not exist `.

Comment: Same result, `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Numbe‌​r`.

Comment: please check the value of ``$F{soma}`` ... may be there is something wrong for example any non-numeric content. just try to print ``$F{soma}``

Comment: I have a value at database as `90000.00` and it shows "90.000" at the report, and `100.01` at the database and it shows "100,01" at the report.

Comment: if you just print ``$F{soma}`` without any modification except select IFNULL(SUM(valor),0) as soma, its not possible..

Comment: `select IFNULL(SUM(valor),0) as soma` at query and printing `$F{soma}`.

Comment: check the iReport property of textfield where you printing

Comment: `<field name="soma" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>`      `<valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{soma}]]></valueExpression>`

Comment: Are you sure about your database value? run query at console without any GUI

Comment: Well, looking at my java class it is `BigDecimal`, but looking at my database, at the table properties, it says `decimal(19,2)` for the column `valor`.

Comment: Sorry, for me there is nothing abnormal... I have no better solution for now

Comment: No problem, i'll keep searching!

Comment: ,One last thing , is it normal printing just `$F{soma}` to get values like `1.500,20` ?

Comment: not clear? without formatting ``1.500,20`` is not possible for a BIgDecimal

Comment: Asked because it's what im getting now with printing just `$F{soma}`.

Comment: Happy to know that finally you got your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) that has the right `Currency` to format the value. If the default `Locale` is giving you a problem,

- Use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale inLocale)` with the `Locale` you want, e.g.:

  ```
  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
  ```
- Use `NumberFormat.getInstance()` and `setCurrency()` to set the `Currency` you want, e.g.:

  ```
  NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  f.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(…));
  ```

Comment: I get it solved using new `java.text.DecimalFormat("R$ #,##0.00").format($F{soma});` after some time trying, not sure of what was causing the error. But, thanks for the suggestion.